# "Stereo Mix"-like functionality in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio, microphone

I'm currently developing an application that works with live music captured via microphone. That makes it pretty hard to test though, what with me working in a shared office and all. I'm currently testing it by loading external MP3 files from within the app, but that's far from optimal.

What I'm trying to do is to somehow reroute the sound coming from the speakers as if it came from the microphone. I've read about the Stereo Mix option that comes with some sound card drivers on Windows, but I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

PulseAudio looks promising, and I found [a guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio#Recording_example_using_PulseAudio_and_Audacity)) that shows how to achieve something similar, but it only deals with recording the sounds in Audacity and so uses some options specific to Audacity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Andrey

**Update:** I've been playing around with `pacat` and trying to make a loop as described in [this question](https://superuser.com/a/128797/107854). However I've been struggling to get the devices paired up correctly. The devices listed in `paman` are:

Sinks

- alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo

Sources

- alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
- alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo

It's the first time I've had to deal with audio devices so I'm not completely sure what I'm doing. The best result I got was from

```
pacat -r -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor | pacat -p -d alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

which made the mp3 track I was playing in the background layer over itself continuously with a second's delay, which made for a cool if slightly disturbing effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect an MP3 player via a [DI box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DI_unit) to the mic-in socket on your test PC.

> A DI box is a device typically used in recording studios to connect a high-impedance, line level, unbalanced output signal to a low-impedance microphone level balanced input,

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. I was hoping for a software-only solution since this is a personal project and I've got more or less zero budget for it. I'll keep your answer in mind though. My housemate has all sorts of sound-related gadgets so he might have one of these.